# What is "Flow widgets" and how we can use & benefit from them

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, azure-ad

I am reading documents about Power Automate from Microsoft Docs and in below link, they are talking about "Flow widgets":

[Integrate Power Automate with websites and apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/embed-flow-dev)

But I am not sure how we can benefit from this? and what does "flow widgets" do exactly? unfortunately the link does not show a picture about how the "flow widgets" looks like, So I am confused. Any advice?

Second question, From my understanding is that "Flow widgets" can be embedded inside public websites, so how users will be using them? For example should the public users login to Power Automate before? and can they use non-Microsoft accounts? as not all public users have Microsoft accounts. In other words what are the differences between "Flow Widgets" and embedding what ever page we want using the standard HTML iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Flow widgets in Power automate are used to embed the content from Power automate to your app or SharePoint site or any other website.

You can embed the content/widgets like:

1. List of flows
2. Power automate Approvals
3. List of templates
4. Trigger manual flows

You can use flow widgets in two ways:

1. **Unauthenticated widget**: You don't need the JS SDK or an access token in this case. You can simply build widget URL & embed it using `iframe` (see example given below).
2. **Authenticated widget**: You will need to use Power Automate's JavaScript Software Developer Kit (JS SDK) to embed the flow widgets and provide the required user access token. User will need license in this case to see his/her approvals or to run the flow manually.

**Example**: I have added below embed/iframe code on SharePoint modern page using **Embed** web part which shows the available Power automate flow templates for SharePoint connector:

```
<iframe width="1200px" height="600px" src="https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/widgets/templates/?q=SharePoint
&pagesize=6&destination=new"></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: ok i see, so at the end the "flow widgets" are embedding the MS flow inside external pages using iframe? so let say inside our external website (might be a word press website) we added this iframe then the users will still need to login to MS Flow as usual to be able to see the iframe content (the "flow widgets" in this case)?

Comment: second question, why do we need SDK if this is just embedding the Flow inside iframe? where iframe will embed another document within the page,, so why do we need to reference SDK? i am a bit confused? thanks

Comment: Pages like flow templates are publicly available & no need to authenticate using Microsoft account. But when you try to use that template & starts creating flow, you will have to login with account.

Comment: To see the content like your existing flows or approval requests, you need to login with the user account. So, to read such content, you need authenticate & pass the access token to flow APIs as mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/embed-flow-dev#configuring-your-client-application).

Comment: let say inside the external site we are showing the Pending approvals for the login user using "Flow Widgets", then if login is not required, then what the anonymous users will see in this case?

Comment: second question, what do you exactly mean by "flow templates " ? third question, why do i need to pass the access token to the flow APIs, i mean if the user is already login to MS flow , then they should be able to see the iframe content inside the browser, without having to worry about anything,, am i correct or i am missing something ?

Comment: are you able to advice more? your replies are just mentioning what i have already read inside the documentation .

Comment: You will not be able to use the `approvalCenter` widget with `iframe`  (unauthenticated way). It will throw `404 - Sorry, there's been a disconnect` error. To use such widgets you have to use the authenticated/SDK way.

Comment: 2. You can find the **flow templates** [here](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/). 3. To call Flow APIs, you have to pass the user access token (using AAD app), else how browser will know which credentials to use in flow widgets added within external website?

Comment: for the 3rd question, this is how the standard HTMl iframes work, you can embed another application inside a host page,, and the browser will automatically login you for the embedded content.. in other word why do i need to use the SDK way if i can already embed the Flow using standard HTML iframe

Comment: You cannot embed all the widget types using HTML iframe.

Comment: Hi @johnGu, does this help for your original question in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, flow widgets are some sort of iFrames located in a host document, where this document points to Power Automate Designer, in other words you can integrate a specific Power Automate functionnality into third-party applications !

---

### Widget Architecture

---

Power Automate widgets work by embedding an iframe that references Power Automate into a host application. The host provides the access token that's required by the Power Automate widget. Power Automate's JS SDK enables the host application to initialize and manage the widget life cycle.

[image]

You can find more details here on [Microsoft Official Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/embed-flow-dev#:%7E:text=Flow%20widgets%20are%20iframes%20located,Widgets%20can%20be%20simple.)

Comment: if it is an iframe then why we need to authenticate?  as iframe will automatically login the user if he/she are already login to power platfrom ?

Comment: Yes, automatically via the code !